# Wait until function finishes before continuing the main (one threaded)

Tags: c++, wait, sleep

Let there be a one-threaded programm, which calls a large `functionLarge()`, which needs to finish before the next codeline in the callers `main` Function. Assume the function is well broken down and just takes long. 
In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435229/c-function-completing-before-other-function-finishes) `.wait()` is suggested and I wonder if its better than:

```
  bool done = false;
  // returning true at the end, modifies bigObject by refrence
  done =   functionLarge(bigObject);
  while(!done) { usleep(1000); }

  //...can now continue
```

Are there better approaches, without the returning `bool`?

Comment: Just stop using `bool` and let the program be ran in normal execution order?

Comment: Your approach is bad because the value of `dont` won't magically change after assigned, so the loop will be taken either 0 or infinity times.

Comment: you don't enter the while until `functionLarge` is done.

Comment: Could you extend on "you dont enter before `functionLarge` is done". So at least it still blocks, also not as expected

Comment: If this is truly a "one-threaded program" then functionLarge will be completely done when it returns, and there will be no reason to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're massively over-complicating this, because **that's already how it works**.

As you said, it's *single-threaded*. Control will be passed to `functionLarge` and will not be returned until that function has completed.

You do not need to do anything. No need for any `bool`s or `while` loops. With a single thread, what is going to be doing the "waiting", exactly?

```
int main()
{
   doThis();
   nowDoThis();
}
```

Comment: The object is modified by `functionLarge` and in the next line added to an [interactive marker server](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/interactive_markers/html/classinteractive__markers_1_1InteractiveMarkerServer.html#a7b688e99eeb8cdcc3f8d03c49ec5ef70). Without the construct I am not able to visualize the marker and I tracked it down, that the object is added before its done preparing by `functinLarge`. Also a simple `usleep(1000)` does work, so I assume its timing. I can directly visulize the difference in [Rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes#Running_the_Code)

Comment: ...oh I think I got it, the mistake was further up: the server is a dynamically allocated object and obviously not fully initalized, when I hand over the `bigObject`.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.